# Is there any way to get new device frames for Developer Tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

Chrome Developer Tools has an option named "Show Device Frame" but when I enabled it only shows for some devices, like Moto G4 and Ipad.

Is there any way to download more device frames for other devices?

[image]